# Initialize vue v-select, before options query resolves

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building a SPA with vue and firebase, and one of the views is a datatable, with a filter on the data in a dropdown.

The data is quite slow to load, so what I want is for the v-select to fill in with a default value (which is a filter id and name), before the query that returns all the filters options resolves.

I have tried several approaches, but I don't understand why this one does not work. **What is the correct way to do this?**

*Note: it is important that the filter value have both a name, and an id, as the id drives the logic for data filtering*

```js
<template>
   <v-select 
      :items="items" 
      v-model="currentItem" 
      item-value="id" 
      item-text="name" 
      label="MySelector">
   </v-select>
   [...]
   <v-data-table> The data table elements are filtered using the value of v-select.</v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      props: {
         currentItem:{
            Array,
            default: () => {return {id:"rtegergergrg2r", name:"default-name"}
         },
      },

      computed:{
         items() { ... some slow query that returns a [{id:name}] }

         }
   }
</script>
```

I have also tried returning a default in `items`. It does not work, and the v-select appears as empty at page load (screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a best idea in this case to run query in the computed property.
I would do it like so:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        currentItem: { type: Array, default: () => { id: 'default-id', name: 'default-name' }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                { id: 'default-id', name: 'default-name' }
            ]
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.items = // some slow query that returns a value
    }
}
```

This way you're sure that you will have some default value visible in the filter.

Additionaly i'm a little concerned about using `v-model` with props. It could result in warning about mutating props directly and that is no good.